# Combine .csv with same name in folder

Tags: r, csv, file-io, data-manipulation

I have a folder that looks like this

```
> list.files()
[1] "2013-09-13(1).csv" "2013-09-13.csv"    "2013-09-14.csv"    "2013-09-15.csv"   
[5] "2013-09-16.csv"    "2013-09-17.csv"    "2013-09-18.csv"    "2013-09-19.csv"   
[9] "2013-09-20.csv"    "2013-09-21.csv"    "2013-09-22.csv"    "2013-09-23.csv"   
[13] "2013-09-24.csv"    "2013-09-25.csv"    "2013-09-26(1).csv" "2013-09-26(2).csv"
[17] "2013-09-26.csv"    "2013-09-27.csv"    "2013-09-28.csv"    "2013-09-29.csv"   
[21] "2013-09-30.csv"
```

As can be seen, there are files with the same names, such as "2013-09-13(1).csv" & "2013-09-13.csv". What I want to do is create some form of loop that can detect such problems and rbind the files

```
2013-09-03 <- rbind(2013-09-13.csv, 2013-09-13(1).csv)
write.csv(2013-09-03, file="2013-09-03.csv", row.names=FALSE)
2013-09-26 <- rbind(2013-09-26.csv, 2013-09-26(1).csv, 2013-09-26(2).csv)
write.csv(2013-09-26, file="2013-09-26.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

So at the end, I can see this:

```
list.files()
[1] "2013-09-13.csv"    "2013-09-14.csv"    "2013-09-15.csv"   "2013-09-16.csv"
[5] "2013-09-17.csv"    "2013-09-18.csv"    "2013-09-19.csv"   "2013-09-20.csv" 
[9] "2013-09-21.csv"    "2013-09-22.csv"    "2013-09-23.csv"   "2013-09-24.csv"
[13] "2013-09-25.csv"    "2013-09-26.csv"    "2013-09-27.csv"    "2013-09-28.csv"
[17] "2013-09-29.csv"    "2013-09-30.csv"
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soemthing along these lines should work, haven't run it myself.

```
library(data.table)
patternstomatch <- gsub(list.files(), pattern = ".csv", replacement = "")

for (i in patternstomatch)
{
  filestorbind <- list.files(pattern = i)
  if( length(filestorbind ) > 1)
  {
    rbindeddataset <- rbindlist(lapply(filestorbind, read.csv))
    write.csv(rbindeddataset , file = paste(i,".csv", sep = ""))
  }
}
```

patternstomatch will contain "2013-09-13(1)","2013-09-13","2013-09-14", etc. the loop will look for each of these strings in the filenames. If multiple files are found matching a pattern it will read them all, rbind them and write it out as ".csv".

Using the gsub approach on the first line, you can then find files that have "(" in their file name and use file.remove to delete those files.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works with this change :)

    rbindeddataset <- rbindlist(lapply(filestorbind, read.csv))

Comment: Please edit my answer accordingly, since you noticed it :). I'm kinda new to SO but I think editing fetches you points as well.